# Can the ?# added in the URL by an input be avoided?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did this JS component but in some pages as codepen it crashes when I click submit because the the button adds a "?#" to the URL (running locally) and is like it changes to another page, this happens the first time I post a message, can be avoided? or is a normal thing of submit?

```
<div id = "typeSection">
<label for="message">Message:</label>
<form action="#" id="typeForm">
<label for="message"></label>
<textarea id= "character">0/280.</p>
<input type="submit" id = "addButton" value="Submit">
```

This is the component running in CodePen:

https://codepen.io/LeonAGA/pen/vroRBB

Comment: Please simplify the problem, too much code to wade through

Comment: You should cancel the `submit` event on the form.

Comment: The final solution was sent  the argument event of the submit listener to the function addMessage and cancel all action with the e.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" id="typeForm">
```

Action value might be the reason why adding # after the URL, try assign "" instead of # symbol

Answer (score 0):

when you add 'action="#"' in the form tag below:

`<form action="#" id="typeForm">`

it redirects the page to the current url with a "#" appended on to the end. If you put:

`<form action="" id="typeForm">`

you shouldn't have to worry about the "#" anymore.

Comment: The "less bad" method would be an `action="javascript:void(0);"`, which works wonders.

Comment: Changing the form `action` will not stop this from re-loading the page on submit.